# How to group three Eventlistener mouseover on 1 if statement in JS

Tags: javascript

I want to set the background of a wrapping collapsible section to a certain image through JS, when the user hovers over one of the 3 divs inside the container.
I wrote this code , I don't know if it is correct (apparently it is not):

```
function BGchangeOnHover() {
if ((row2_4.addEventListener("mouseover") == true) || 
(row2.addEventListener("mouseover")) == true) || (row4.addEventListener("mouseover")) == 
true) {
myCollapsible3.style.backgroundImage = "url('/images/untitled2.png')";
}
}
```

please, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) has no return value, thus your condition can never be true.

Comment: Without the HTML it is hard to figure out what you're trying to achieve. It also makes it impossible to give you a correct answer since we have to guess what your HTML structure is. -> [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: No worries; I just figured out the solution :

Comment: I think you can create one handler and bind the 3 divs' `mouseover` event to it